# plotly: how to scale down y-axis

Tags: scale, plotly.js

plotly graph, is shown below.

[image]

I want it to scale it by yaxis shorter as below

[image]

I tried this to scale down

```
        Plotly.newPlot( 
            TESTER,
            traces, 
            { 
              margin: {'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0,'t':10},
              xaxis: {'automargin': true},
              yaxis: {'automargin': true,scaleanchor: "x", scaleratio : 1},
              legend: {x: 0, y: 1.2}
            },
            {displayModeBar: false}
        );
```

but get an error

```
 WARN: ignored yaxis.scaleanchor: "x" to avoid either an infinite loop and possibly inconsistent scaleratios, or because this axis declares a *matches* constraint.
```

Comment: This looks like you just want to reduce the height of the chart.